# Could someone enlighten towards how to make the div 'quiz-container' redirect from the 'drop your name here' to the actual quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let me endeavour to properly explain what I aim to reach with the small code that I have written.

My intention is to make a single question quiz with two alternatives and an outside submit button for them, but I want to use the div quiz-container for both cases; given that I want to insert a name beforehand and do the quiz afterwards.

I'm a beginner when it comes to JavaScript and I just couldn't manage to make radio buttons specifically to the two alternatives and make everything work. Here is [my Code](https://codepen.io/rafaelle-duarte/pen/wveWrBL).

HTML

```
    <body>

  <p class="mini_container">
    Is it a bother if I quiz you a bit?
  </p>
  <div class="quiz-container">
    <span class="name">Drop your name here</span>
    <form id="name">
      <input type="text" id="name-text">
      <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="submit_button_2">
    <button type="submit" id="submit_2">Submit</button> 
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    body {
  background: #011910;
}
.quiz-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #a6a6a6;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px rgb(3, 125, 80);
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(52, 0, 52);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 95px;
 
}
.answers label {
  display: block;
}
input {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
 
}
button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color:rgb(1,25,16);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color:rgb(144,238,160);
  border: 9px rgb(255,189,182);
  border-radius: 15px;

  
}
button:hover {
  border: 20px rgb(255,189,182);
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.mini_container {
  background: #b4ecb4;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px rgb(3, 125, 80);
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-shadow: 1px 4px rgb(254, 254, 227);
}
.buttons {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
.submit_button_2 {
font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var name = "";
var quizQuestion = {
  question: "Do the Brazilians speak...",
  alternatives: {
    1: "Brazilian Portuguese",
    2: "Spanish"
  },
  correctAnswer: "1",
  incorrectAnswer: "2"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your submit button inside the form, and added Javascript to populate the `quiz-container` after the user submits their name. There's an event handler that lets the user know if they got the answer right or wrong.

```js
var name = "";
var quizQuestion = {
  question: "Do the Brazilians speak...",
  alternatives: {
    1: "Brazilian Portuguese",
    2: "Spanish"
  },
  correctAnswer: "1",
  incorrectAnswer: "2"
};

document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    let container = document.querySelector('.quiz-container');
    container.innerHTML = '<form id="quiz">';
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(quizQuestion.alternatives)) {
        container.innerHTML += `<input type="radio" name="choice" value="${key}"> ${value}`;
    }
    container.innerHTML += '<button id="submit2" type="submit">Submit</button></form>';
    
    document.getElementById('submit2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log('asdf')
        e.preventDefault();
        var selected = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked');
        if ( selected && selected.value == quizQuestion.correctAnswer ) {
            alert('Right!');
        } else {
            alert('Wrong!');
        }
    });
})
```

```css
    body {
  background: #011910;
}
.quiz-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #a6a6a6;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px rgb(3, 125, 80);
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(52, 0, 52);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 95px;
 
}
.answers label {
  display: block;
}
input {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
 
}
button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color:rgb(1,25,16);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color:rgb(144,238,160);
  border: 9px rgb(255,189,182);
  border-radius: 15px;

  
}
button:hover {
  border: 20px rgb(255,189,182);
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.mini_container {
  background: #b4ecb4;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px rgb(3, 125, 80);
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-shadow: 1px 4px rgb(254, 254, 227);
}
.buttons {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
.submit_button_2 {
font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="mini_container">
  Is it a bother if I quiz you a bit?
</p>
<div class="quiz-container">
  <span class="name">Drop your name here</span>
  <form id="name">
    <input type="text" id="name-text">
    <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a very valuable answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Javascript:
// I Use Jquery for you to easily understand the codes in it and i have added some comments also to indicate what's going On.
// 
// first i Imported the Jquery cdn

// Let the All other Documents Load Well before loading the Jquery code
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Once the Continue Button is Clicked, Do this
  $("#next").click(function() {
    $(".languages").toggle();
    $(".namer").toggle();
  });

  // Once the Back Button Is Clicked, Do this
  $("#prev").click(function() {
    $(".languages").toggle();
    $(".namer").toggle();
  });

  // Check for the Radio Button if Its Correct
  $("button").click(function(event) {
    // Prevent form submit on the browser
    event.preventDefault();
    // check for the correct option and give the right result
    var checked = $("input[name=language]:checked");
    if (checked.val() == "yes") {
      alert("You're Very Correct");
    } else {
      alert("You're Wrong");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS:

in the css code, i made some adjustments, I have commented on the newly adjusted codes below: */

body {
  background: #011910;
}

.quiz-container {
  width: 500px;
  background: #a6a6a6;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px rgb(3, 125, 80);
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(52, 0, 52);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 95px;
}

.answers label {
  display: block;
}

input {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
}


/* Newly added */

.btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(1, 25, 16);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: rgb(144, 238, 160);
  border: 9px rgb(255, 189, 182);
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/* Newsly Added */

btn:hover {
  border: 20px rgb(255, 189, 182);
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(1, 25, 16);
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: rgb(144, 238, 160);
  border: 9px rgb(255, 189, 182);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

button:hover {
  border: 20px rgb(255, 189, 182);
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.mini_container {
  background: #b4ecb4;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px rgb(3, 125, 80);
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 35px;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-shadow: 1px 4px rgb(254, 254, 227);
}

.buttons {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.submit_button_2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 490px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
}


/* Newsly Added */

.languages {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <!-- i Tweek some of your codes Here
  
  HTML
  
  In HTML code, i created different Divs for different sections adding all the codes to your already created quiz-container container. -->

  <p class="mini_container">
    Is it a bother if I quiz you a bit?
  </p>
  <div class="quiz-container">
    <form id="name">
      <div class="namer">
        <span class="name">Drop your name here</span>
        <input type="text" id="name-text" name="name">
        <input type="button" class="btn" id="next" value="Continue">
      </div>
      <div class="languages">
        <span>Do the Brazilians speak...</span>
        <input type="radio" id="yes" name="language" value="yes">
        <label for="yes">Yes</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="no" name="language" value="no">
        <label for="no">No</label><br>
        <input type="button" class="btn" id="prev" value="Back">

       <div class="submit_button_2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit_2">Submit</button>
      </div>
      </div>
      
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't use jQuery in questions that aren't specifically about jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much! I intend to learn jQuery soon and your answer is massively valuable.

Comment: i am happy that it helped